# How do I seal around an outdoor rated wall mounted luminary?

Tags: electrical, exterior, waterproofing, stucco

What's the proper way to seal a exterior wall mounted luminary from water entry?  I was unable to find one for purchase with any sort of gasket, and it appears that any water sheeting down the wall will simply pass through the fixture:

[image: sealing recessed round junction box in stucco]

The pictured fixture reads "suitable for wet locations" on UL sticker, and is from a respected brand.  There's a weep hole at the marked bottom.  I checked every wall mount fixture at several home and building supply stores and they all had the same basic design.

Caulk is an option of course, but caulk must be maintained over time.  A retrofit 'mounting block' might help, but those need caulk also.  Are there better options for keeping the inside of the light reasonably dry?

Comment: Was the luminary listed as appropriate for exterior use? Most so listed come with a gasket.

Comment: Check the UL sticker (not quite readable in this picture) - if it does not say "rated for wet locations" [or possibly "suitable for wet locations"] go buy one that does - which do indeed usually include a gasket.

Comment: @Ecnerwal zoom the picture, it clearly states "suitable for wet locations" on the UL sticker.  What's a brand that includes a gasket for flush wall mount (not surface box mount)?

Comment: @bib can you cite an example of such a fixture (for wall mount)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*What's the proper way to seal a exterior surface mounted lamp from water entry?*

Here's what I ended up doing.  I applied a bead of paintable silicone caulk directly to the stucco, tooled it for good adhesion, and smoothed it with a soapy finger.  This in essence built up a nearly invisible gasket.  The fixture already had a weep hole. Fastening the fixture compressed the gasket and made a seal that won't tear with future motion:

[image: caulk as electric light fixture gasket on stucco wall]

I then ensured all three wire nuts were pointed with the open end down, so condensation does not build up and rust the spring wires.

Comment: So you let the silicone cure fully, before mounting the light?

Comment: Exactly.  Initially I put it up too fast, I had to wait a few days.

Comment: Why not just caulk around where the light is mounted after it's installed?

Answer (score 3):

What's the proper way to seal a exterior wall mounted luminary from water entry?

Caulk it with a high-quality, paintable silicone caulk like this. I have been using this caulk for 8 - 10 years and have never had to re-caulk after applying it.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you use a *neutral cure* silicone for this, not an acetic acid cure, otherwise you'll corrode the heck out of what's in the j-box!

Answer (score -1):

Old post I know...I just wanted to share a product I found:
Sigma Electric 14002
[http://www.amazon.com/Sigma-Electric-14002-Round-Gasket/dp/B00C3YDIZA](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C3YDIZA)

Comment: I'm torn on whether this counts as spam, Jerry; you signed up today just to post this link to an Amazon product. I'm not saying it is; it just smells that way.